# How Much Grease to Put into the CV joint?

Tags: axle, cv-joint, cv-boot

I'll be replacing my CV boots soon and was planning to clean out all the old grease and put in new grease.  Should I pack the whole thing full of grease, including the boot, or is just packing the joint / bearing itself sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no grease in the boot.  The CV joint casing doesn't need packing fully with grease.  Pack enough in to cover all the moving parts.  If a sachet of grease is included in the kit, then there usually is enough for one joint.